# Is there is way to create payload for Json Array in Zapier?

Tags: angular, zapier

i want the payload in this format

[image]

I created all the field using Input Designer in zapier but I am unable to do for Messages field as it is in JSON ARRAY 
please how to create JSON ARRAY in Zapier.

Right now I used dictionary datatype for MESSAGES FIELD

[image]

Comment: Are you doing this in the dev platform? Also, is the picture the current input or expected output? I think you need to add more to this question because its lacking some details for me to help.

Comment: Thank you for showing interest i was abled to solve the problem